# How to set Gabor filter parameters to extract wrinkle features

Tags: opencv

I am trying to implement a wrinkle feature extraction method using Gabor filters in OpenCV C++ as outlined in this study:

Choi, Sung Eun, et al. "Age estimation using a hierarchical classifier based on global and local facial features." Pattern Recognition 44.6 (2011): 1262-1281.

The filters will have as input patches of skin from a face image, and need to extract thick and fine wrinkles. I don't know what parameters to use for wrinkles since most examples on the internet deal with edges formed by objects. After getting the output image of the convolution, I need to find the mean and variance of the magnitude response.

It would be great if I found a study on forming Gabor kernels for wrinkles, sample code, or even a neat way to figure out the best parameters.